# jQuery append running twice by itself, multiple append, double append

Tags: jquery, append

HTML:

```
<body> 
<p><a href="#" class="link" >Apples</a> <a href="#" class="link" >Berries</a> <a href="#" class="link">Carrots</a></p>
<select id="list"></select>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var item = $(this).text();
    $('#list').append('<option>'+item+'<\option>');
});
```

It should append new values from the HTML link tags such as apple or carrot but when I click on it it does this (get two lines for each one)

**Results:**

[image: results]

Evey click results in a two options one with the word the other with a blank. Even more odd it seems to work if I take out the html part of things.. Just use text.

Comment: Brandon was nice enough to add my image for me.  That is about it see the gap. It add two lines for every click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is causing this behavior, but the issue is that

```
$('#list').append('<option>'+item+'<\option>');
```

should be a forward slash

```
$('#list').append('<option>'+item+'</option>');
```

Comment: It's probably because the browser doesn't understand what `<\option>` is, so it tries to "auto-correct" stuff.

Comment: That was it.. Gesh.. Thank you But good to document this strange behavior!   I changed it to /option and it worked..  Always mundane details..   ( I must have put a decimal place in the wrong place or something, I always do that!.. ) - Office space..  Thank you Brandon!

Comment: The browser is treating the incorrect `<\option>` as the start of a blank option, rather than the matching end tag for the `<option>` tag, which is kind of what I'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

This approach works fine for me.

```
$(function(){

   $('.link').click(function(){
      var item = $(this).text();
      $('<option>'+item+' </option>').appendTo($("#list"));
    });;

});​
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/mKTzx/4/